# Facebook API to retrieve wall feed

Tags: facebook

I've never done any facebook development and am working on a project which I only require to pull out wall stream from a certain user. Is there such an API I could use for this purpose?

Comment: You have to give more information about the project you are working on. There are a lot of SDKs you could use.

Comment: Am going to use Python mainly in this project and I will require to retrieve the wall posts of a specific user of his posts into a table in my system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Facebook exposes a generic API. You can write your own methods of accessing it, or you can use Facebook's libraries (if your preferred language is available). Check out the following link to get started:

[Getting started](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web)

Comment: I tried going through the link you gave me, it seems like most the API to create applications with facebook and they kind of not useful in my case because they depending on iframe, html and js to get the job done.

Comment: Check out the Graph API: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api and the python SDK: http://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're happy with JSON, just using the graph API is a good start.

e.g. https://graph.facebook.com/starbucks/feed

Not too hard to pull that down with Python and put the data in a table...

Answer (score 0):

Though this is an old post, still i am putting in my reply. This might be helpful.

I am using php sdk and here is code for getting the users wall posts (includes posts by other users as well)

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '101874630007036',
  'secret' => '2090c8d645ae93e7cacee2217cd3dc0c',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user)
{
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} 

else 
{    
    $params = array('scope' => 'read_stream');

    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
}

if ($user)
{    
    $comments = $facebook->api('/me/home'); 
}
```

here $comments contains the wall post json data.