# Plugin to show the Facebook Wall in my website?

Tags: facebook, plugins

I'd like to show my Facebook Wall in my website.

I found this [Show posts on my WebSite from Facebook's wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252138/show-posts-on-my-website-from-facebooks-wall) where it seems easy, but when I change the "URL of post"
from:

```
https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers/posts/10151471074398553
```

to mine "

> `https://www.facebook.com/myPageID`

I get this message:

> **The publication of Facebook is no longer available . It may have been
>   deleted or changed their privacy settings** .

I guess my URL has a wrong format or I have the wrong permissions.
Also I think that my url should include an id. Where can I found this id?

**UPDATE:** I found the ID. I tried with the url and the ID of the page with all these options:

> `https://www.facebook.com/274153376021189`

and also:

> `https://www.facebook.com/posts/274153376021189`

and also:

> `https://www.facebook.com/Quiropractica-Vilanova/274153376021189`

and also:

> `https://www.facebook.com/Quiropractica-Vilanova/posts/274153376021189`

But I can't get it working, I get the same message. What am I missing here?

Comment: Please try. It helped me 

[Stackoverflow - facebook-api-to-retrieve-wall-feed][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702237/facebook-api-to-retrieve-wall-feed

Comment: @Attu thanks I will try, but I have cero experience with facebook development. I'd like to make this plugin works